# ContentPane changing size after initialization - why?

Tags: codenameone

I noticed that sometimes the content pane changes its size after initialisation and was wondering why that would be.

Here's some code to demonstrate this in the simulator - run it in the simulator and watch the output - smaller skins have smaller differences:

```
public class FormScrollExtras extends Form {
    private int entrytally = 0;
    private Runnable runnableLog = null;

    public FormScrollExtras() {
        setTitle("FormScrollExtras");
        setScrollable(false);
        setTensileDragEnabled(false);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.setScrollableY(true);
        contentPane.setTensileDragEnabled(false);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("This form logs the content panes height and layoutHeight - right after init and whenever an entry is created.");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(textArea);
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage2.MATERIAL_ADD);
        floatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(getContentPane(), Component.RIGHT, Component.BOTTOM);
        floatingActionButton.addActionListener((e) -> newEntry(contentPane));
        contentPane.getParent().layoutContainer(); // Doesn't make a difference
        runnableLog = () -> {
            Log.p("x/y, height/layoutHeight: " + 
                    contentPane.getAbsoluteX() + "/" + contentPane.getAbsoluteY() + ", " + 
                    contentPane.getHeight() + "/" + contentPane.getLayoutHeight());
        };
        runnableLog.run();
    }

    private void newEntry(Container contentPane) {
        contentPane.add(new Label("" + ++entrytally));
        runnableLog.run();
        contentPane.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently the toolbar changes its size

Comment: So I wonder why the toolbar changes its size when something is added to the contentPane

Answer (score 0):

Without the numbers related to the height change it's hard to guess but you can verify this by looking if this only happens for iOS skins or only for Android skins.

I'm guessing it would be because of the status bar space that is reserved in iOS and impacts the toolbar height. Notice that during construction elements aren't laid out yet so there is no size guarantee at this stage. There are several callbacks that are more deterministic such as `initComponent()` or `laidOut()`.

Comment: `laidOut()` is called three times before the forms constructor finishes and two more times. Only then the toolbar has its final size.

Comment: `initComponent` of the form is not called at all.

Comment: Using `com.codename1.ui.Display.callSerially(Runnable)` in the constructor I am able to get the final sizes of toolbar and contentPane. Is there a better way to determine the termination of initialization?

Comment: Overriding `com.codename1.ui.Form.onShowCompleted()` seems to be the hook to be used, right?

Comment: On show completed means everything finished completely. Normally we use `initComponent()` as it happens before anything is visible on the screen (before the transition). `callSerially` is an implementation detail, you postpone the operation to the next EDT cycle. If it works great but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Is it a bug that the forms `initComponent()` method is not called?

Comment: As far as I can tell by the code it should be invoked on `Form` are you sure it isn't?